# Unable to parse incorrectly formated HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

Here is my node.js program:

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom');

var site = 'http://www.lefigaro.fr/international/2011/08/09/01003-20110809ARTFIG00389-un-premier-mort-dans-les-emeutes-en-grande-bretagne.php';
var jquery = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js';
jsdom.env(site, [jquery], function(error, window) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(window.$);
});
```

and the output:

```
/home/matt/Desktop/nodejs/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom.js:245
        window.document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
                                        ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null
    at /home/matt/Desktop/nodejs/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom.js:245:41
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at /home/matt/Desktop/nodejs/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom.js:230:22
    at [object Object].callback (/home/matt/Desktop/nodejs/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom.js:289:17)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/home/matt/Desktop/nodejs/node_modules/request/main.js:294:21)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:64:17)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/matt/Desktop/nodejs/node_modules/request/main.js:281:54)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:81:20)
    at HTTPParser.onMessageComplete (http.js:133:23)
    at Socket.ondata (http.js:1232:22)
```

I think it doesn't work because the HTML from the source page is not correctly formated. Is it really because of that and is there a way to fix it if it is ?

Thanks

Comment: This error tells you that `window.document.documentElement` is null. However, the posted code does not show where it is defined. Can you investigate or post the relevant code?

Comment: Please post some sample HTML that reproduces this error.  It's virtually impossible to fix a bug you can't repro.

Comment: what version of jsdom are you using?

Comment: I only use the code posted above to get the error. To see the HTML you can go look at the source of ` `http://www.lefigaro.fr/international/2011/08/09/01003-20110809ARTFIG00389-un-premier-mort-dans-les-emeutes-en-grande-bretagne.php` . And my version of jsdom is `0.2.3`

Answer (score 2):

Well it seems that jsdom till now supports only DOM Level 1 and some common browser provided methods, but `documentElement` is from DOM Level 2 spec.

Ref:

1. http://jsdom.org/documentation
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.documentElement

Comment: jsdom.org hasn't been updated in quite a while, my appologies.  We are currently sitting at 100% compliance with level1 and level2 (xml/html/events)

Comment: it looks like jsdom.org has been hacked or taken over -- i'm seeing a lot of "articles" about hair loss and NLP